# Implementation improvement on a case switch programme

Tags: c

I can tell that there will be a memory leak on this and am looking for improvements / the standard way of doing things as far as these kind of problems go.

(e.g. how an experienced / pro use on C would implement this)

This is a simple case switch programme. Its purpose is to give it PizZa and give you back pIZza.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char changeCase(char ch){

    if ( (int)ch < 65 || (int)ch > 122){
        return ch;
    }else if ((int)ch < 91){
        return (char)(ch + 32);
    }
    else{
    return (char)(ch - 32);
    }
}

char* toUpper(char* string){
    size_t size=strlen(string);
    char* temp = (char*) malloc(size);

    while (*string != '\0'){
        *temp = changeCase(*string);
        temp++;
        string++;
    }

    return (temp - size);
}


int main() {

    char* string = toUpper("PIZa");
    printf("%s",string);

    return 0;
}
```

This results in a memory leak since the memory from malloc is not freed. What would be better? Allocating memory outside the function and giving the pointer to that memory to the toUpper function? Other idea?

Comment: Just free the memory with `free(string);` before the `return 0;`.

Comment: @Blaze Would my solution be acceptable? Would that be implemented as a best possible solution? Wouldn't it be better to delegate allocating and deallocating memory to a single function?

Comment: Not directly related to your memory leak but an experienced programmer would not skip the terminating `\0` when duplicating a string. And using cryptic magic numbers (`122` or `65`) instead of more meaningful represenations (`'z'` and `'A'`) would be avoided as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The de facto standard rule is that the part of the code that did the dynamic allocation is also responsible for freeing it. So if your function was in some file "toupper.c", then there should have been some manner of clean-up function available in that same C file.

However, the best solutions separates memory allocation and algorithms. This means that a better way to write this function is this:

```
void toUpper (char* dst, const char* src)
{
  while (*src!= '\0')
  {
    *dst= ...
    ...
    dst++;
    src++;
  }
}
```

Here, the caller can allocate space for `dst` as it pleases, it's no business of the algorithm. For example:

```
char str1[] = "hello world";
char* str2 = malloc(strlen(str1) + 1);
toUpper(str2, str1);
...
free(str2);
```

Just make sure to document the function so that the caller knows that they have to allocate space for `dst` - to be at least as large as `src`.

As a side-note, `char* temp = (char*) malloc(size);` is wrong, you didn't allocate room for the null terminator. Also your algorithm must make sure to copy the null terminator into the destination buffer.

Comment: Would it be possible to use the same src and dst?

Comment: @kaptsea Maybe, maybe not. It could cause undefined behavior on some systems if you copy between memory areas that overlap. If you want to safely modify the buffer in-place, you should change the function to `void toUpper (char* buf)`

Comment: I suppose then that this would like something like that:

    ```void toUpper(char* string){  
    while (*string != '\0'){  
        *string = changeCase(*string);  
        string++;  
    }
    *string = '\0';
    }```

Answer (score 1):

> This results in a memory leak since the memory from malloc is not freed.

Actually there is no memory leak in your code. All allocated memory will be freed when the program terminates.

A memory leak occurs in a **running** program when the program no longer holds a pointer to the allocated memory.

Example:

```
int main() {
    char* string = toUpper("PIZa");
    printf("%s",string);

    string = toUpper("BRead"); // This causes a memory leak because after this
                               // line there is no longer any pointer to the
                               // memory allocated in the first call of toUpper

    string = NULL;             // Again this causes a memory leak because after this
                               // line there is no longer any pointer to the
                               // memory allocated in the second call of toUpper

    return 0;
}
```

Note: Even leaked memory will be freed when the program terminates. Memory leaks are (mainly) a problem in "long" running programs.

> What would be better? Allocating memory outside the function ...

Well, it's a matter of taste.

As an example: The widely used (but non-standard) `strdup` function handles allocation inside the function and requires the caller to free the memory later on.

For a function that reads an unknown amount of characters as user input it can also be nice to do `malloc` (and `realloc` as needed) inside the function.

There is really no right or wrong here. You are the designer so you decide. It's all about the "function contract", i.e. the documentation of the function - how to call it and what it will do.

Comment: What I was looking for was a more generalized approach to this kind of problems really. Avoiding memory leaks is a thing of habit (at least so far this is the impression I have been given) and thus building that habit is always beneficial. This "programme" would not really exist all on its own in the world, it would rather be part of a whole, and in the whole, this code would leak :)

Comment: @kaptsea I'm not sure what you mean. There is no leak in your code. If you want to free all allocated memory before terminating the program, all you need to do is to add `free(string);` in `main` just before `return 0;`